# Can't use subscribed data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a collection in mongo with many document like this:

```
{
  name: "someUniversityName",
  campus: ["someCity", "anotherCity", "anotherCity2"]
}
```

I wanted to make a GET request and fetch them. That's **done** and displayed correctly in my terminal with `201 res.status`. As you can see in the code below, I did that with `subscribe` that uses `doIt()` from `helper.service.ts`.

**What I can't manage to do is:** assign only the `name` property from my fetch universities to a variable in `universities.component.html`. **SO THEN** I can assign those values to:

```
<select
  name="universidad"
  class="form-control"
  id="univer"
  (click)="doIt()">
    <option
      *ngFor="let univ of univs"> 
        {{ univ }}                <-- DISPLAY THEM HERE -->
    </option>
  </select>
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

I console.log `this.universidad` from the html file and `name` and `sede` properties are `undefined` which means that the assignment that's supposed to be done in `.subscribe` to `this.universidad` is not being completed????????

---

**My code**

universities.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from '../../../../../../../node_modules/rxjs/operators';
import { HelperService, universidad } from "../../../../../services/helper.service";
import { Observable } from '../../../../../../../node_modules/rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usuarios.component.scss']
})
export class UsuariosComponent implements OnInit {
  universidad: Object = {
    name: String,
    sede: [String]
  }
  universidadModel: String

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private helperService: HelperService
  ) { }


  doIt(){
    this.helperService.getListado()
      //clone the data object, using its known config
      .subscribe((data: universidad) => this.universidad = {
        name: data['name'],
        sede: data['sede']
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

helperService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export interface universidad {
  name: String;
  sede: [String]
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelperService {
  private toggleTrigger = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  toggle = this.toggleTrigger.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient

  ) { }

  listadoUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3000/universidads/listado';
  getListado() {
    // now returns an observable of universidad
    return this.http.get<universidad>(this.listadoUrl);
  }
}
```

html view

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="universidad">University list</label>
        <select
          name="universidad"
          class="form-control"
          id="univer"
          (click)="doIt()"
          >
          <option
            *ngFor="let univ of universidad | async"
            >
            {{ univ }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="display-1 mt-4">{{univer}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards.

Comment: what is the data(response) structure when you get it in the subscribe and what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Your question is not clear, with *ASSIGN THEM HERE* you mean: display them here? You are making `universidad`  as an object, you can't loop over objects, the variable created in `subscribtion` should be an Array of Objects with each object resembling one option.

Comment: I don't know what is in `data`. I tried to put a console.log somewhere inside `this.helperService.getListado()` and it complains everywhere.

Comment: You are binding `*ngFor="let univ of univs"`, where is `univs` in the component?

Comment: try console log inside subscribe. You should get it there!

Comment: Aragorn just a typo of the post, didn't fix it.

Comment: alokstar it returns a `data` object with an array of my universities and all the information inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I wrote this inside `ngOnInit` so it calls on initialization. I just had to loop through the objects from the array of objets the request returned me. `universidadListado` is just an array that receives the names so then I can loop through them with `*ngFor`.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/universidads/listado')
      .subscribe(res => {
        for(let key in res){
          this.universidadListado.push(res[key].name)
        }
      })
```

Now my `select` display all the names of universities as `options` dynamically.

Thanks for your help,
Regards.